# duplicate headers when using Handsontable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, handsontable

I am working with Handsontable, and the headers are shown twice.
What is causing this to happen?

[image]

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

          var data = [
              ['2009', 0, 2941, 4303, 354],
              ['2010', 3, 2905, 2867, 412],
              ['2011', 4, 2517, 4822, 552],
              ['2012', 2, 2422, 5399, 776]
            ],
            container = document.getElementById('example'), hot;

          hot = new Handsontable(container, {
            data: data,
            minSpareRows: 1,
            colHeaders: true,
            contextMenu: true,
            colHeaders: ['Cuenta Única', 'Número Comercio', 'Número PDV', 'Máximo Cuotas', 'Grupo Afinidad'],
            manualColumnResize: true,
            colWidths: [120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120],
          });
        });
</script>

<div id="example"></div>
```

Comment: Can you please include your entire html above or make a jsfiddle?  I'm able to make it work in fiddle without duplicate headers here:  http://jsfiddle.net/ojdoowLw/

Comment: Thank You. I made a new html file out of the project and worked well. Then it must be something in the framework I'm using to interfere in style. I'm using a pretty old framework known as "Mambo" and there must be the problem. Thanks for your help I will keep trying.

Comment: At least I managed to hide it by entering the following css style:
.ht_clone_top {display: none! important; }

Answer (score 1):

Here's the deal. As you may be aware, Handsontable allows you to freeze columns. To do this, there are ALWAYS two sets of tables rendered. You correctly found it by noting that the second table is called `ht_clone_top`. This clone is what allows you to freeze tables, so if you remove it, even though you will fix your bug, you will not be able to freeze rows.

I can tell you what I think might be your problem as this is a common issue. You probably have CSS which modifies your table element. Unfortunately, you have to ensure that you also modify the clone tables. It's a really tough problem to solve given the nature of CSS but with enough effort, you can fix this issue!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a small error in your code.

replace this line `container = document.getElementById('example'), hot;` with the following code
       `container = document.getElementById('example');`

Comment: Thank you, I tried your suggestion but not worked. I'll keep trying.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem by removing the `padding` from the Hansontable container `DIV` element.