# Handsontable duplicate tables

Tags: angular, handsontable

Two issues:
1. I keep receiving duplicate tables when using `@handsontable/angular`. If I create two tables, then the words don't overlap anymore. 
2. Unable to select any of the cells if I use `colHeaders` and `rowHeaders`.

Not exactly sure what is going on. I suspect it's conflict with bootstrap?

Top image shows the overlap of the header. Second image is when I add another `hot-table`

one table:

```
  <hot-table class="hot inline-block vert-top" width="{{ window_width }}"
    [data]="data" [colHeaders]="colHeaders" [rowHeaders]="rowHeaders"
    [tableClassName]="['table', 'table-hover', 'table-striped']"
    >
    </hot-table>
```

[image]

two tables:

```
  <hot-table></hot-table>

  <hot-table class="hot inline-block vert-top" width="{{ window_width }}"
    [data]="data" [colHeaders]="colHeaders" [rowHeaders]="rowHeaders"
    [tableClassName]="['table', 'table-hover', 'table-striped']"
    >
    </hot-table>
```

[image]
component.ts

```
  ngOnInit() {
    let headers = [];
    this.rowHeaders = ['Revenue', 'Gross Profit', 'SGA', 'Total Operating Expense']
    this.selection = Object.keys(this.income);

    for (var j=0;j< this.rowHeaders.length;j++){
      const temp = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < this.income['Year'].length; i++) {
        let head = this.income['Year'][i] + this.income['Type'][i] + this.income['Qtr'][i] 
        if (headers.indexOf(head) < 0 ){
           headers.push(head);
        }
        temp.push(this.income[this.rowHeaders[j]][i])
      }
      this.data.push( temp )
    }
    this.colHeaders = headers;
  }
```

[image]

Also tried this:
[duplicate headers when using Handsontable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32019489/duplicate-headers-when-using-handsontable)

I tried freezing the headers instead. Same result.

Answer (score 0):

handsontable stylesheet shouldnt be imported from the app's global stylesheet but rather from `angular.json` config file

simply add the path in `node_modules/../handsontable` in `styles` config.